# Dynamic Height UITableViewCell data wrong order

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview

Is it appropriate to call `[tableView beginUpdates]` and [`tableView endUpdates]` in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`?

I am trying to dynamically expand cell heights based on the content within the cell.  When I use [`tableView beginUpates]` and [`tableView endUpdates]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the output looks ok.  However, once I start scrolling, data in the cells becomes ordered incorrectly and sometimes the bar separator between table cells disappears.

Should I not be using `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to specify your dynamic cell heights in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because the table view wants to know its content size up-front. Any changes you make to the cell's frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be overridden by the table view, so what you're attempting won't work.

If your heights are derived from the cell's content, consider using the prototype approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard/14127936#14127936). Also, if you can use a 3rd party library, check out [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It does dynamic cell height for free if your custom cell class implements the `TLDynamicSizeView` prototype. Try running the [Dynamic Height](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Dynamic%20Height/Dynamic%20Height/DynamicHeightTableViewController.m) sample project.