# Obtain row height dynamically in UITableViewCell with multiple nibs

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, nib

I have a `UITableView` with the `UITableViewCell` loaded from different Nib files when the user taps or double taps a cell i.e *there are three different Nib files of varying height*, *one each for normal, tap and double tap.*

How do I identify the loaded nib within `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for dynamically setting the row height?

Comment: Can you share your code, so i can try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dequeue the cell in `heightForForAtIndexPath` and check it's height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId = @"Cell";//set cell ID here based on your view controller's logic
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

You can cache the dequeued cells in a dictionary if you're concerned about performance. There is a more detailed discussion of this approach in [Retrieve custom prototype cell height from storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard/14127936#14127936) (contrary to what the title might imply, the use of storyboard is not required).