# how to adjust UITextview height based on String dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a simple `textView` who's data gets populated dynamically. I want to resize the height of the textview once the data is populated so that I don't see a vertical scroll nor the text gets clipped.I want to do this task programatically. I have a label which should be placed 20 px below height of textview like "interested".I am trying to making the code.But i got some problems like Alignment issues. If i can run the program the output will display like this.

[image]

this is my Program.please help me anybody.

```
 lblHobbies = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 310, 300, 20)];

 lblHobbies.text=@"Hobbies";

 lblHobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

 lblHobbies.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

 [scrollView addSubview:lblHobbies];

 lblInterests = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 420, 300, strSize.height+30)];

 lblInterests.text=@"Interests";

 lblInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

 lblInterests.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

 [scrollView addSubview:lblInterests];

 NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]};

 CGRect rect =
         [tViewhobbies.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];

 tViewhobbies=[[UITextView alloc]init];

 tViewhobbies.frame=CGRectMake(10, 330,300, rect.size.height);

 [tViewhobbies setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

 tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

 tViewhobbies.delegate=self;

 [scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];

 NSDictionary *attributes1 = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]};

 CGRect rect1 =
         [tViewInterests.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:attributes1
                                           context:nil];

 tViewInterests=[[UITextView alloc]init];

 tViewInterests.frame=CGRectMake(10, 450, 300, rect1.size.height);

 [tViewInterests setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

 tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

 tViewInterests.delegate=self;

 [scrollView addSubview:tViewInterests];
```

Comment: for both support see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215199/dynamically-size-uitableviewcell-according-to-uilabel-with-paragraph-spacing/19217965#19217965 supports both iOS6 and iOS7

Comment: hay see my answer hope u get some idea, just use that code insted of yours... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go through below code hope helps u

```
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
  UILabel *lblHobbies = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x + 2, self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y + 2, 75, 40)];
  lblHobbies.text=@"Hobbies";
  lblHobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
  lblHobbies.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

  [self.scrollView addSubview:lblHobbies];


  //add this after the hobbies textview so u need to calculate the height, so wy dont you put some helper method that returns the height for the text
  //i took some long text that u want to display
  NSString *str = @"BARCELONA, Spain -- Nokia is targeting emerging markets with three low-cost smartphones that use Google's Android operating system rather than the Windows Phone software from Microsoft, which is about to buy Nokia's phone business";


  CGSize hobbiesTextViewSize = [self calculateHeightForString:str];
  //now set the hobbiesTextView frame and also the text
  UITextView *tViewhobbies = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x + 2, self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y + 40, hobbiesTextViewSize.width, hobbiesTextViewSize.height+ 5)];
  tViewhobbies.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
  tViewhobbies.text = str;//set the text hear
  [self.scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];

  //now add the lblInterests label
  UILabel *lblInterests = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x + 2, self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y + lblHobbies.frame.size.height + hobbiesTextViewSize.height + 2, 75, 40)];
 lblInterests.text=@"Interests";

 lblInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

 lblInterests.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
 [self.scrollView addSubview:lblInterests];


 NSString *str1 = @"Nokia will ditch many of the Google services that come with Android, which Google lets phone makers customize at will. Instead, the new Nokia X line announced Monday will emphasize Microsoft services such as Bing search, Skype communications and OneDrive file storage. Its home screen sports larger, resizable tiles resembling those on Windows phone.";

   //now calculate the height for Interests text
  CGSize interestTextViewSize = [self calculateHeightForString:str1];
  UITextView *tViewInterests = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x + 2, self.scrollView.bounds.origin.y + lblHobbies.frame.size.height + lblInterests.frame.size.height + tViewhobbies.frame.size.height + 4, interestTextViewSize.width + 2, interestTextViewSize.height+ 2)];
  tViewInterests.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
  tViewInterests.text = str1;
  [self.scrollView addSubview:tViewInterests];



}

 //our helper method
 - (CGSize)calculateHeightForString:(NSString *)str
{
   CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
NSDictionary *systemFontAttrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:labelFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableAttributedString *message = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:systemFontAttrDict];
CGRect rect = [message boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){320, MAXFLOAT}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];//you need to specify the some width, height will be calculated
size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height + 5); //padding

return size;


 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response.I am trying to run your code.But i got exception this line " NSMutableAttributedString *message = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:systemFontAttrDict];"

Comment: what's the exception ... !!..?  it should work wait i will try

Comment: clean and build the project

Comment: did u replaced all from beginning to end ... ? like what i did

Comment: if u still get the error try out in seperate project by adding only scrollview to xib and just copy and past above code in -(void)viewDidLoad` method and the helper method

Comment: @Shah i got still exception " NSMutableAttributedString *message = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:systemFontAttrDict];". In this line of code "str" place what i am specify??

Comment: it is just the incoming string value u just put str `- (CGSize)calculateHeightForString:(NSString *)str` only, it working fine for me i tested it

Comment: @shah i got same exception brother that line of code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48253/discussion-between-shan-and-user3222991)

Comment: come to chat we will discuss there

Comment: can u post full method, how you are calling the helper function

Comment: @shah i  paste your helper method fully.

Comment: come to chat if u are free , i did't see your update

Comment: u are using `boundingRectWithSize ` it is deprecated, past entire method how u are calling that helper method edit your code and past the new code

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
+(CGFloat)getLabelDymanicHeightOfStringWithText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont *)font andFrame:(CGRect )frame {
     CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, 999999.0);
     int height = 0;

 NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                       nil];

 if (IS_IOS_6)//iOS 6 macro
 {
     CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                          constrainedToSize:maxSize
                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
     height = size.height;
 }
 else
 {
     CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:attributesDictionary
                                             context:nil];
     height = frame.size.height;
 }

 return height+5; 
}
```

Pass this method your text text font and frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom UITextView to fix the problem:

Kindly check it out: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Textview will set height dynamically based on input string from the user.

Hope, This will help you,

:)

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYou can use label.

```
myLabel.text = @"Your String";
CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320,MAX_HEIGHT_YOU_WANT_TO_SET) 
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect frame = myLabel.frame;
frame.size.height = labelSize.height;
myLabel.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the height of the textView to the height of the textView.contentSize.height. Doing this you textView will update and show all the text it contains.

```
textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, textView.frame.size.width,textView.contentSize.height);
```

Hope this helps you.
Happy Coding :)