# Resize UILabell in iOS 7.1 in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, resize, uilabel

I have a table view with custom cells. I'm using Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1. I would like to adjust a UILabel height based on the length of a string and also dynamically adjust the height of the cell to fit the label.

In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.titleLabel sizeToFit];
```

Some seem to resize correctly, others don't. As for the height of the cell, I can't get it to update based on the height of the label.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215199/dynamically-size-uitableviewcell-according-to-uilabel-with-paragraph-spacing/19217965#19217965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     return [self dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:indexPath]+20;

}


-(CGFloat)dynamicHeightAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(275, 9999);
   UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:11];
   CGSize stringsize = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:myFont
                                                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                                             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
   return stringsize.height;

}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly for me with resizing the table view cells. I am still running into an issue with the label itself though.Even though the label extends to all the way from the left to the right, sometimes the text either ends up like:

Text
Text Text
Text (one on top of the other)

Instead of: text text text text (in one line extending the whole cell)

or you click on the cell, push a view controller, and come back and it appears as it should but as you scroll, you see some that are messed up.

Comment: please provide screenshot if you can

Comment: I have uploaded the photos into a folder on Dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4016fxw8qfutpoq/jtVwMw8zQs If you need more, just let me know. Some strings seem to be calculating correctly but truncating - others are working but stacking weirdly.

Comment: It also seems that when you see the messed up labels, click the cell, push the new VC, and go back - the ones that were messed up, seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The cell's height is determined solely by the value you return from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is a `<UITableViewDelegate>` method.

If you want to have the cell height be dynamic, you would need to perform a calculation in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` based on the particular string that appears at that index path.

If you plan on doing a lot of scrolling, this calculation could get expensive and cause performance issues. If that is the case, I'd recommend caching the computed heights or computing them all at once and storing them in an array parallel with your data source.