# How to adjust text label height according to the content

Tags: ios, swift

```
class MojoCell :UITableViewCell{ // cell for Mojo    

@IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var qNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answer: UISegmentedControl!

func configure(_ mojo: MojoModel) {

    self.qNumber.text = mojo.questionNumber

    let text :String = "123456789-123456789-123456789-1234567889-123456789"
    self.question.sizeToFit()
    question.numberOfLines = 0
    question.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    question.text = text
    question.sizeToFit()      
}
```

I used the above code to adjust the height of the label according to the content of the UIlabel. But It does not work I expected. It only shows the portion of the text.

[How It looks lie on X-CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHqf7.png)
 [How It looks lie on Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUQFx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically increase height of UILabel & TableView Cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052361/dynamically-increase-height-of-uilabel-tableview-cell)

Answer (score 0):

UITableView have automaticDimension. It will make your row dynamic, you don't need to give **heightForRowAt**.

You need to put **estimatedRow height = "put your row height"**. Then in **rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension**

Try this in your code it'll work for you.
If you don't understand above code, then try this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return "put your estimated height for row"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code in `func configure(_ mojo: MojoModel)`

```
 templabel.text = "Your text here" <br/>
 templabel.textAlignment = .center <br/>
 templabel.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:templabel.intrinsicContentSize.width,height:templabel.intrinsicContentSize.width)
```