# heightForRowAtIndexPath is incorrect when cell contains uilabel with new line characters

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wanted to display address information in a uitableviewcell and am using a custom cell with autolayout. I figured that instead of having seperate labels for the address fields, i would have a single label and concatenate the address fields together and use the newline character "\n' so that each address field appears on a new line in the label, then i set the label number of lines to zero so it auto-expands.

That part works fine, what is not working is when I try to calculate heightForRowAtIndexPath, its under-reporting what the label size would be so the address is getting truncated.

e.g. here is some code extracted: It seems like the boundingRectWithSize is not taking into account the newline characters perhaps? Anyway I am tempted to not use a single label but instead have separate fields which would be more work but I think it would not run into these issues.

```
        NSString *description= [self getAddressDescription:_delegate.shoppingCart.shippingAddress]; // formats address fields into single string with newline characters 
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
                [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                        initWithString:description
                            attributes:@
                            {
                                    NSFontAttributeName: [ViewHelper getDescriptionFont]
                            }];

CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){200, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   context:nil];
CGSize descriptionSize = rect.size;
return kParentChildDefaultSpace + + descriptionSize.height + kParentChildDefaultSpace;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prototype cell method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard/14127936#14127936) combined with `[label sizeToFit]`. There is a working [sample project here](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/tree/master/Examples/Dynamic%20Height).