# iOS UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableview that lazy loads images of all different sizes.  When an image loads, I need to update the specific cell, so I figured out I need to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.  But when I use this method, it still calls the heightForRowAtIndexPath method for every single cell.  I thought the whole purpose of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is that it will only call heightForRowAtIndexPath for the specific row you specify?

Any idea why?

```
[self.messageTableView beginUpdates];
[self.messageTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.messageTableView endUpdates];
```

Thank You

Comment: have you tried using only..  [self.messageTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Comment: You mean instead of wrapping it in beginUpdates and endUpdates?  Yes I tried that and it still tries to redo the height for every single cell.  Really annoying as I am expecting it to call heightForRowAtIndexPath just for this particular cell.

Comment: Am I right in believing that it should only call heightForRowAtIndexPath for this one cell?  Or does it call this method again for every cell in the table?

Comment: I think it should call for only row that you are reloading. I dont know why it is calling for all visible rows. It may depends on how you displaying your cell. Try without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Comment: How do you create the cell without dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?  So what I have determined is that the only difference between reloadData and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths in my app is that reloadData calls cellForRowIndex for each visible cell, whereas reloadRowsAtIndexPaths calls cellForRowIndex just for the one cell.  But they still both call heightForRowAtIndexPath for every single cell in the table uggh

Comment: Try this code cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"]; it will initiate new cell object for each row without reusing visible rows.

Comment: tried that and my tableview just comes up empty.  My cells have custom classes, not sure if that is why, but it just doesnt load anything in the UI when I do it this way...

Answer (score 7):

`endUpdates` triggers a content size recalculation, which requires `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. That's just how it works.

If it's a problem, you could pull your cell configuration logic outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and reconfigure the cell directly without going through `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. Here is a basic outline for what this could look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId = ...;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    [self tableView:tableView configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell configuration logic here
}
```

Then, wherever you're currently calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, you do this instead and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.messageTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self tableView:self.messageTableView configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: The problem is not cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It is the fact that heightForRowAtIndexPath is called for every single cell in the UITableView when I do any type of reload.  I stopped using beginUpdates and endUpdates, but this still happens

Comment: @Jesse You may have missed my point. If you move your cell's configuration logic out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` into a standalone method (which you would call from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can update the cell's configuration by calling the method directly instead of using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` (which indirectly calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) thereby bypassing the table view's reload behavior that involves recalculating the content size (which indirectly calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath`).

Comment: Hey Tim. I called configure cell method but I got autolayout constraint conflict, it says my cell height is 300 whereas my picture height is greater than 300. It seems calling configure cell doesn't update the height of the cell. Is there anyway to inform table view to update the height? I tried to manually call the heightForRow method right before calling configure cell again.

Comment: @Zhang you'll need to reload the rows in order to have the table view update their heights.

Comment: but if I call reloadRowsAtIndexPath it'll crash the app, as mentioned above question?

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is the server returns the width and height for each picture in the cell. Web developers logic is the reverse of iOS, they give the browser the content and the browser automagically resize the cell to the height of its content whereas iOS requires developer to provide the height before it generates the content =/

Comment: @Zhang I don't see where a crash is mentioned. However, there are solutions for auto-sized cells. iOS8 supports auto-sized cells by setting the table view's row height property to: `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. In iOS7 and below, there are techniques such as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard). If you're getting a crash, consider posting a new question with detail. Its difficult to discuss in comments.

Comment: Why not just call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths without begin/end updates? I see in the documentation begin/end updates is necessary only for "insertions, deletion, and selection operations", this isn't any of those.

Comment: @Ixx that recalculates height too (see question's comment thread)