# UITableView with Various Custom Cells of differing heights within UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am building a IOS app homepage which basically consists of the following structure -

[image]

Which is basically a UIView which contains a nested UIScrollView which inturn contains a TableView with 3 Custom Cells.

I pull data out of a dynamic array and filter it into the relevant cell - all works fine other than two issues I cant work out -

1- The custom cells are different heights in the storyboard but when the app is compiled they are always the same height - is it possible to set an auto height on the UITableView Row?  If not can anyone explain how I can apply the correct height to each cell?

2- The TableView / View which wraps the table view need to expand to make all dynamic cells visible - how can I achieve this?

below is my tableview method for reference -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"CellFeed";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierArtNo =@"CellArtRecNo";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierBook =@"CellBooking";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    feedData *f = [self.HpFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString * ArtPString = @"articleP";
    NSString * ArtNoPString = @"article";
    NSString * ArtBook = @"booking";

    if([f.FeedGroup isEqualToString:ArtPString]){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier  
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
        CellHp_RecArticleWithImage *cellImage = (CellHp_RecArticleWithImage *)cell;
        cellImage.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellImage.artTitle.text = f.FeedTitle;
        cellImage.artImg.text = f.FeedDesc;
        cellImage.artDate.text = f.FeedDate;
        cellImage.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        return cellImage;
    }
    if([f.FeedGroup isEqualToString:ArtBook]){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierBook 
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
        CellHp_BookingAlert *cellBook = (CellHp_BookingAlert *)cell;
        cellBook.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellBook.HeadlineLbl.text = f.FeedTitle;
        cellBook.TextBoxLbl.text = f.FeedDesc;
        //cellBook.DateLbl.text = f.FeedDate;

        return cellBook;
    }
    else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierArtNo 
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
        CellHp_RecArticleNoImage *cellNoImage = (CellHp_RecArticleNoImage *)cell;
        cellNoImage.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellNoImage.artTitle.text = f.FeedTitle;
        cellNoImage.artImg.text = f.FeedDesc;
        cellNoImage.artDate.text = f.FeedDate;
        cellNoImage.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        return cellNoImage;
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got custom UITableViewCell subclasses like `CellHp_RecArticleNoImage` or `CellHp_BookingAlert` (may I suggest renaming them to something a little less headache-inducing? ;) ).

In that case, if you only have 3 different cell types, you could do this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CellHp_BookingAlert class])
    {
         return 123.0;
    }
    else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CellHp_RecArticleNoImage class])
    {
         return ...
    }
     ...
}
```

Or, you could make all your custom classes implement a `height` method for a cleaner solution and in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you could just get the cell and call its height method.

Re. Question 2, use [UIView's `sizeToFit` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW11) as Tim mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement below method to identify the height of cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
   *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks @hussain, how do I apply the height of the cell and the height of the surrounding view?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can derive static or dynamic (data driven) cell heights from the storyboard by dequeuing them in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` according to the procedure outlined here: [Retrieve custom prototype cell height from storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard/14127936#14127936)
2. I'm not exactly sure I understand this question, but you can get the `contentSize` of the table view if you're trying to size the table to fit the content.