# iOS: Tableview with custom cells does not scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a nav bar orchestrated set of tableviewcontrollers to display a hierarchy of data. The bottom level of data is displayed in a custom tableviewcell, which has its content described in a xib, and results in a required cell height larger than the default. I posted another question on how to programmatically extract the resulting cell height, but no usable answers, so I now implement heightForRowAtIndexpath to return a hardcoded value that is the height in the xib attributes panel. But, when the table is displayed with more rows than can fit in the normal display size (480h,320w), the bottom row is chopped off as expected, but I can't scroll it to see the rest of the row. I've searched rather extensively, but nothing has helped. I poked at various attributes (tableview sizes, scrollingEnabled, etc.) but they all seem as expected values (e.g., scrollingEnabled is true). One post suggested that no scrolling would occur unless the contentSize was larger then the frame, so I looked at those values, and  it sounds promising, in that my frame size is a typical 460h x 320w, but, my contentSize is 0 x 0! Further searching (e.g., "setting contentSize" or "contentSize is 0") didn't clear anything up. I thought contentSize was computed for free from the table row count and their heights, so how could I be getting 0? Even going back to allowing a default row height by not implementing heightForRowAtIndexpath still resulted in a 0 contentSize. Some searches suggest turning off autoLayout for the custom table cell, but still the same. So, what might be going awry? Thanks for any thoughts or guidance.

Update: Sorry, I confess! I had originally been developing on a mac mini with a regular USB mouse, where scrolling in the simulator was left button down and drag. I recently switched to an iMac with the magic mouse. I'm now so used to just dragging my finger on the mouse to scroll code, web pages, etc., that I didn't think to try clicking and holding the left mouse "button", and then dragging the mouse. When I did, everything worked as expected. I had really thought things were hopeless when any similar variables/values in the app on the mini were equal to those on the iMac, but it was just me getting tricked by fancy technology. Sorry for the distraction.

Comment: "I posted another question on how to programmatically extract the resulting cell height, but no usable answers" See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660004/retrieve-custom-prototype-cell-height-from-storyboard/14127936#14127936

Answer (score 0):

set your tableView's frame and your cell's frame correct,and implement 
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
in your UITableView to give a right height.

If that doesn't work try set your tableView.autoresizingMask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`|`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`;

which can help you with the size of the tableview

Comment: As mentioned in post, heightForRowAtIndexPath is already implemented, and returns a literal 110. I displayed the current autoresizingMask value, and it is 18, implying both Flexible Width and Height. So, I'm basically already doing these.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My tableView would't scroll when the content exceeded the tableViews frame.

The problem for me was that I had "Use Autolayout" checked but no constrains on the tableView. Adding vertical and horizontal space constrains on the tableView fixed my problem

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting here. I don't have a xib for the tableview, so how might Use Autolayout be modified? Do in code like Baoyu's post modifying tableview.autoresizingmask below?

Comment: Ok. Didn't get that. Good you found the solution!